# LoadRunner Viewstate

Tags: viewstate, loadrunner

In other posts I have experienced some issues with record and playback of an app and I was told that viewstate could be something that I should look into regarding this issue.

I have a chunk of code here that is *working* during replay (not the same app though), but the point I am making is the same:

```
web_submit_data("overview.jsf", 
    "Action=https://wasapp-q1.adeo.no/some/sa/overview.jsf?execution=e4s1", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://wasapp-q1.adeo.no/some/sa/overview.jsf?execution=e4s1", 
    "Snapshot=t4.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=overviewSearchForm:searchCriteriaId", "Value=01024531232",   ENDITEM, 
    "Name=overviewSearchForm:j_id111", "Value=Get ", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=overviewSearchForm_SUBMIT", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=javax.faces.ViewState", "Value=cxeGmdwmyti6LtCKFbfHsLGYkE6QJ+eGozLlfTsidCNXrT2KqQ+JviDhkv7MCtdmlnxzQZVOMo9uO9ZrjUUdfpfFJMwwRfg/A09/Em5tTUJxNZ6fUe5LGK9oitXNeeBh0M5Yd7nwXn5uj1bLQzluR09kUUA2dnwrXajncw==", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

This chunk of code is *not working*:

```
web_submit_data("hello_world_2", 
    "Action=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/wow/behold/83512/considervilkar?5-1.IBehaviorListener.0-vurdereVilkarListe-vurdereVilkarRepeater-4-considerVilkarListItem-considerHoved-innerPanel-vilkarDetaljer-vilkarForm-vilkarsregelValg",
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://d26jbsl00003.test.local:8080/vedtak/behandling/83512/vurderevilkar?5", 
    "Snapshot=t4.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=vilkarsregelValg", "Value=OPPFYLT", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

Both code chunks call web_submit_data. Assuming that Viewstate has something to do with the replay issue of the last one, what does:

```
"Name=javax.faces.ViewState", "Value=cxeGmdwmyti6LtCKFbfHsLGYkE6QJ+eGozLlfTsidCNXrT2KqQ+JviDhkv7MCtdmlnxzQZVOMo9uO9ZrjUUdfpfFJMwwRfg/A09/Em5tTUJxNZ6fUe5LGK9oitXNeeBh0M5Yd7nwXn5uj1bLQzluR09kUUA2dnwrXajncw==",
```

actually mean in LoadRunner context? Could it have something to do with my second chunk of code not working (not having a Viewstate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is something which changes with every request.   So, ViewState is something you will need to correlate for almost every request (when it is present).   There is also jsessionstate that shows up on Java apps, ViewState is typically associated with ASP and ASP.Net

Comment: Ok, Thank you. 
Then I will use jsessionstate in my case. I will do a manual correlation With a web_reg_save_param and left and right boundry right? Because it is coming from the server I Guess?

Comment: The variable name and its use is dependent upon what is there when you record the stream.   If jsessionstate or viewstate is not present then it is not added.   LAbles are not altered from one to the other.   You leverage what is there or you wind up with HTTP 500 errors all over the place for posting data that the app does not not how to process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX Truclient, this will help you alot.
No correlations needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate is a value which changes with every login .It is a 64 bit encoded value returned by the server upon login.

you can try correlating the value ,from the response of the previous request.